# Using HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: http, ssl, https

I have a website that user have to loggin to. I want to use HTTPS so make a secure encrypted connection to the server to check the user name and password.

Currently on my server i have a folder called httpdocs, this is where my website is store, i also have a folder called httpsdocs.

Now as i stated my website is stored in httpdocs so logically i would go to http://website.com

But i found that if i go to https://website.com i get a secure connect to the pages stored in httpdocs.

Anyway, my question is, whenever i go to another link i loose the secure connect (URL goes back to http://) So how do i keep it all secure? Would i have to use the full URL in the href because that seems a bit lame instead of just using href=page2.php .

I'm new this area of website developing, but i am experienced in developing if that helps you.

Thanks a bunch for the help.

Some basic tutorials or reading material would be awesome if anyone knows of anything good?

Thanks again.

Comment: You are possibly using absolute urls or using a variable in your website (whatever language its written in) that holds the "base url" for your website. You will need to post some code/html or possibly a link to your website for a better answer.

Comment: I don't have absolute URLs, i stay clear of that. Thats my problem, if i use absolute for exmaple https://mysite.com/page3.php it'll be secure, but i don't know how to do it with a relative link. Is there something server side that i could change, like a value or something like that? I'm using CentOS on my server

Comment: No, using `href="page3.php"` will use whatever protocol you're on - is it perhaps a .htaccess issue?

Comment: Okay, i've managed to get it to stay in the protocol..... Someone thought they should use an absolute URL (I hate taking over other peoples work) Still don't know how to set up the site so that it opens the https when you just type in the domain. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: see my answer to your question.

Comment: Using redirects to fix this problem is not secure - see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476324/using-https-instead-of-http/8476853#8476853) to the answer by @Prisoner - you have to eliminate the HTTP links in the first place. Can you explain what the links look like in the HTML that gets delivered to the browser? Are you using some content management system that could rewrite your URLs behind the scenes? I would recommend using the full https:// links if that is the only way to solve your problem instead of using the redirect hack, for security (and even performance) reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question in the comments you should use mod_rewrite (assuming its enabled):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

that will send any webpage to https.

Comment: This is **not a secure solution** because if every link is accessed with insecure HTTP which then gets redirected to secure HTTPS then between every click and redirect you are vulnerable to pretty much the same attacks as if you had all of your communication done in HTTP. Specifically there is a possibility of a man in the middle attack that would send something else than a redirect, or a session hijacking or evesdropping on sensitive data that is sent with cookies, query parameters or post data. The correct solution would be to eliminate the HTTP traffic in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that? @rsp

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `http://foo.com/path` in urls, use `//foo.com/path` instead (or, even better, if you stay on the same server, use `/path` - it surely works). Doing full urls is bringing redundancy and brittleness. Avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)**:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Basically, you can force the browser ([unless it's IE<12](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#Browser_Support)) to always use HTTPS by adding this header to the secure site's configuration:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
```

This can also be combined with a 301 (PERMANENT) redirect for the non-secure/HTTP site's configuration, also [outlined](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#Server_Side) on the above referenced site.

Additionally/Alternatively, you can set the [base href](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) on your "website.com" pages by adding something like this towards the top of the `<head>` tag:

```
<base href="https://website.com/">
```

This will set all relative urls on the page (including links, stylesheets, scripts, images, etc.) to use the HTTPS site's root as their base. Depending upon the structure and size of your site, however, you will want to verify for each page that its base href and/or the urls  within the page include any necessary path information (i.e. subdirectories). Otherwise a link on http://website.com/some/directory/page.html that points to "otherpage.html" will direct to http://website.com/otherpage.html instead of http://website.com/some/directory/otherpage.html . In such cases you would want either a base href of "http://website.com/some/directory/" or the relative url in the link should point to either "/some/directory/page.html" or "some/directory/page.html" (no slash needed in this case).