# Forcing HTTPS over HTTP

Tags: security, .htaccess, http, https, url-rewriting

So I want to force the user to access the https version of my page rather than the http. And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476324/using-https-instead-of-http) post all I have to do is this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But *MY* site resides in a folder within the main directory, so it's in `www.domain.com/Folder`. So should this htaccess code go inside the main directory or in the subdirectory. Because I do not want to change the way the access the main site, only the folder.

Comment: Can we assume this is a PHP collection of scripts and you want to *secure* the access to scripts in some specific directory?

Comment: @Raffaele no the folder contains a whole other page. The reason I want to secure it is because that page contains a registration and login element.

Comment: So the folder **contains the PHP scripts you want to secure**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave it in the root directory but change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(your-directory/.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Keep in mind, though, that before the redirect happens, the cookies and query parameters with possibly sensitive data has already been sent in clear text, so remember to use the [secure cookie atribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie) if you use cookies.

Comment: it was without the leading slash. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

This is a not-so-good method of going about this, especially if you have access to httpd.conf. The better method is to create *TWO* virtual hosts. One for your standard port 80 stuff, which simply has an unconditional redirect to the SSL version, e.g. in pseudo-ish .conf talk:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
   RedirectPermanent / https://example.com
   DocumentRoot /some/fake/path
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost example.com:443>
   normal site stuff here...
</VirtualHost>
```

This has the advantage of leaving the redirect viable even if a config messup disables .htaccess files, plus serving up bogus/non-existent content if SSL dies for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your site can be vulnerable if you're redirecting from http to https. Take a look at this for some more information on that.

http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/

Comment: It should be noted that this attack also hijack simple anchor links on an http site to an https site

Answer (score 0):

seems silly to "force ssl" till they fix the big gaping security hole it opens up in browsers in the name of "site verification"
this has no real basis and there is potential for abuse by a rogue CA, rogue state, or corruption.
(and the "verification" is useless anyway not being based on user wishes not anyone actually looking at the sites - there are plenty of phishing sites out there with "valid" certificates!)

there is way too much misinformation being bandied around about SSL

you get the **same** encryption with a self signed certificate but browsers tell users you site is "untrusted" (with of course no basis - "not checked" or "not verifiable" would be what any warning should actually say - warnings need to be informative not something that just scares users so much most of them just close them without even reading the rest of the warning!)

until this is fixed in browsers I cannot recommend the use of SSL at all in a web site context.

meanwhile all I can recommend to forget port 443 and implement your own encryption layer (or use something like ssh if it doesn't need to be a browser)